# PyTrends Missing Data

Tags: python, google-trends

Today I started facing an issue with the trends over time missing data in the middle.

Instead of the trend data its just 0 for about a year or so then the data picks back up. Last night I had no issues then this morning it started. Tested on multiple machines and different networks.

For example, try running trends over time for keyword "barefoot shoes" you'll see around 2020 the data goes to 0 and then returns to normal.

[image: Image Example]

It only happens for some keywords while others are fine.

Anyone else facing this issue?

I tried a ton of different solutions like running on multiple different machines and networks. Nothing resolved this issue

Comment: This started happening to most people recently, according to the Github. Using the timeframe keyword causes it. Don't know how to fix it.